# What is "silent flag" for mount?

Tags: debian, mount

`man mount`:

> silent Turn on the silent flag.

Who can tell me more about `silent` for mount ?

Or who can provide a specific code example to show this difference(`silent` vs `loud` flag)?

I simple tested no find any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: On what Unix is this?

Comment: @Kusalananda this is on debian jessie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a utility has a `silent` or `quiet`  option, it usually means that the utility will operate without emitting any output.

Sometimes it additionally means that the utility will not output any diagnostic messages (warnings or errors). It may also (but seldom) mean that the utility will always exit with a zero exit status and therefore always act as if the operation that it performed succeeded.

In the case of `mount` (on Debian at least), I'm assuming it means that `mount` will not cause an error message or warning if you try to mount a filesystem with, e.g., the wrong filesystem type.

[The documentation of the `-t` option to `mount` on Debian](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/mount/mount.8.en.html) has the following information:

> If no `-t` option is given, or if the `auto` type is  specified,  `mount`
>                 will  try  to guess the desired type. [...]  If `/etc/filesystems` ends in a line with a single `*`, `mount` will read `/proc/filesystems` afterwards.   While  trying,  all  filesystem  types  will  be
>                 mounted with the mount option `silent`.

This is obviously a case where, if the `silent` option was not applied automatically, there may be a lot of unwanted output.

Comment: Thanks. your answer are very reasonable and helpful me understand this `man mount`,but can provide a specific code example to show difference("silent" vs "loud")?I simple tested no find any difference.

Comment: @illiterate Sorry, I do not have access to a Debian system where I may mount things, so I can not give you a good example of the different scenarios.

Comment: Then what is your using `Unix` or `Unix-like`  system? Maybe I can  test it for this question.

Comment: @illiterate I'm using OpenBSD. `mount` on OpenBSD does not have a `silent` mount option.

Answer (score 3):

Normally a failed kernel `mount()` call will print diagnostic errors to the kernel message log that can provide more details about why it failed than just the error code returned.  The `MS_SILENT` mount option, which `mount` passes to the kernel, suppresses such kernel log output.  It is generally used by scripts that are trying various mount options to probe for any filesystem that can be mounted, where such log output is not likely to be helpful to the administrator.

Comment: Thank you. another reasonable answer, but can provide a code example to show difference between `mount -o loud` and `mount -o silent`?I tried simple test no find difference in output of `dmesg`(as you said `kernel message log`?)

Comment: @illiterate, did the mount succeed?  The difference is when the mount fails -- the kernel prints messages giving clues about the nature of the failure.  The MS_SILENT mount flag has skip those error messages and just fail the call.

Comment: `mount -t noext4  ./1 ./test1 -o loud` vs `mount -t noext4  ./1 ./test1 -o silent`,As far as I saw output of `dmesg`,I can't found a difference.mount is failed as `exit code:32`, `./1` is a `ext4` image file.

Comment: @illiterate, there is no such filesystem.  You need to use a valid filesystem to try to mount, and an image that does not contain such a filesystem.